# Why is matrix of transformation where input and output are matrices larger in size than input and output?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a linear transformation T that takes in a 2x2 matrix and outputs a 2x2 matrix.

From my understanding, the idea of the matrix of this transformation (we will call this $M_T$) is that the matrix multiplication $M_T X$ is the same as the evaluation $T(X)$ for all 2x2 matrix inputs X, that is, the input/output mappings of the transformation can just be represented with a simple matrix.

However, I have then been told that for the transformation T described above, $M_T$ will be a 4x4 matrix.

This is confusing to me because the matrix multiplication between a 4x4 matrix and a 2x2 matrix is not defined, so how is this correct?

Can someone explain this to me?

Or am I misunderstanding the idea of a matrix of a linear transformation?

Comment: Consider the $2\times 2$matrix simply as a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\in K^4$. Then we have the map $T$, given by the matrix $T$, with $Tv=T(v)$. So $T$ is a linear map from $K^4$ to $K^4$. This means it can be written as $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: You have to remember that this is all done in a chosen basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between a linear transformation and the matrix that represents it. You are right to point out that, given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the function from the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices to itself given by $B \mapsto AB$ is a linear transformation because $A(B+B') = AB + AB'$ and $A(\alpha B) = \alpha AB$. Similarly, multiplying by a scalar is also a linear transformation. In both these cases, one doesn't need a $4 \times 4$ matrix to specify a linear transformation.

However, this is not true for all linear transformations of the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices. For example, the transformation
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} d & b \\ c & a
\end{pmatrix}$$
is linear but cannot be obtained by left-multiplying by a $2 \times 2$ matrix (can you see why?).

On the other hand, because the space at hand is $4$-dimensional, every linear transformation can be given by a $4 \times 4$ matrix and every such matrix gives a linear transformation. The caveat is that to write the transformation induced by a matrix as a product of matrices, we need to write the matrix being acted on as a column vector of length $4$. For instance, the $4 \times 4$ matrix corresponding to the linear transformation given by left-multiplying by
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$
is
$$M_A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & b & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 & b \\
c & 0 & d & 0 \\
0 & d & 0 & d
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This is because
$A \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix}$
writen as a column vector is the same as
$M_A \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah, the matrix on the right is written as a column vector. That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The space of all $2\times2$ matrices is $4$-dimensional. Therefore, the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis shall have to be a $4\times4$ matrix.

Take, for instance, the linear map$$\begin{array}{rccc}T\colon&\Bbb R^{2\times2}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^{2\times2}\\&\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}&\mapsto&\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}.\end{array}$$Let

- $E_{11}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $E_{12}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $E_{21}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $E_{22}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Then, if $\mathcal B=\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21}E_{22}\}$, $\mathcal B$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$. Besides:

- $T(E_{11})=E_{22}$;
- $T(E_{12}=-E_{12}$;
- $T(E_{21})=-E_{21}$;
- $T(E_{22})=E_{11}$.

Therefore, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal B$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$